# Embedding PHP code in HTML not working when retrieved from database

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML template that is populated with information from a database and echo'd to user as a complete page. Inside one of the fields that is echo'd I tried to insert some php code  e.g.  but hello doesn't appear to the user, and when I check the source, it is red (nothing appears on the users screen). why would this be? I though that as long as you have a .php file you can embed php code no problem with html. Don't ask why I have the php code stored in a database, it's complicated!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: If you have PHP code in your database, you are 9001% doing it wrong. There's no possible justified reason for PHP code to be in the database.

Comment: Madara is 100% right. If you've got PHP code in your database, it's time to hit the books.

Comment: Actually there is one reason: if you're running an online php test bed like codepad. But yeah *any* other justification is wrong for *so many* reasons.

Comment: php code won't run from string itself. You have to use `eval` here but... Don't do it. Normalize your project!

Comment: How do you use eval in this context of <? echo "hello"; ?>?

Comment: @user1166981 you don't. And anybody who answers that for you is *not* doing you a favour.

Comment: Dave, this is not on the internet, it is on my localhost.. I just need this to work so I can move on with my life! lol

Comment: It's still almost certainly the wrong thing to do, but if you'd like to try justifying it I'd suggest updating the question with some context.

Comment: I don't want to justify it, I am not asking for permission mate.

Comment: You don't need permission, but you are asking for help doing something that really shouldn't be done. We've all been there at some point, but sometimes explaining your reasoning for a particular solution can help clarify the exact problem. There could very easily be a much easier/elegant solution to your problem if you shared the actual issue.

Comment: No one's asking you to justify, but please read this: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: When asking for help, be willing to hear that you're doing it wrongly - and please avoid non-friendly usages of the word "mate" as it isn't conducive to civil exchange. Ideally, try to justify your technical approach, so more experienced members can offer the best possible help.

Comment: halfer, points taken, thanks for that. It is sometimes frustrating to justify why you are doing something when the question is on a technical point, not the 'correct' way of doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use PHP's [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/eval) function, please be careful with this though as it can pose a security risk.

You should really address the underlying issue of why you are storing PHP code in a database.

Comment: Someone said this, but how! <? echo "hello" ?>

Comment: If I save <? $string = 'echo "hello";'; eval($string); ?> into the database, won't that whole thing be echod out as a string though?

Comment: No, you eval() the string from the database.

Comment: The format I am using is to simply echo out the fields from the database with no control like that. whatever is stored in the database is echod, no variables etc..

Comment: All I can change is the PHP saved in the database, I cannot eval it before hand, it must be echo'd.

Comment: Well then you are screwed, you can't do this, its not how it works.